# Is this just another way of asking for the definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Is this the same question just expressed differently?

3. Find

(a)
$\displaystyle \int_2^4 \left(\frac{2}{x-1}-1\right)dx$

(b) The area between the curve $y = \left(\dfrac{2}{x-1}-1\right)dx$ and the $x$-axis over the interval $[2,4]$

Comment: Remove $dx$ from the equation for the curve. Looks like you copied without editing.

Comment: I just copied it straight from the workbook and it's written with the $dx$ for the equation for the curve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is *really* asking for:

$$\int_2^4 \ \left| \ \frac{2}{x-1} - 1 \ \right| \ \text{d}x$$

This is because the original integral *subtracts* area while the function is below the horizontal axis—the reason why, for instance:

$$\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} \sin(x) \ \text{d}x = 0$$

Comment: I get that the original integral subtracts area between [3,4] when it is below the horizontal axis and in some cases it will cancel out completely and return 0 like the example you gave, but how did you get $\displaystyle \int_2^4 |\displaystyle \frac{2}{x-1}|$ from (b) (Where did the -1 go?)

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't see it because it was so close to the $dx$.  Will fix.

Comment: OK that makes sense. So those lines on either side of the function just mean total area, whether it is above or below the x-axis?

Comment: The lines denote the [absolute value function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).  But yeah, $\int_a^b |f(x)| \ dx$ gives the total amount of area between the function and the horizontal axis on the interval $[a,b]$, regardless of whether $f(x) < 0$ anywhere.

Comment: Awesome got it! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

No.  The function $\frac{2}{x-1}-1$ changes sign at $x = 3$.  The integral, version (a), will partially cancel the positive (signed) area with the negative (signed) area.  The area between $\frac{2}{x-1}-1$ and the $y$-axis, version (b), does not have a negative contribution for $x \in [3,4]$.

Comment: So just so I have this right. Part (b) is the same as part (a) except in part (b) we disregard the area below the x-axis? I.e. it is just the area between the curve and above the x-axis?

Comment: @JuanPablo : No.  In (b) all the area contributions are positive, even the part from where the function is negative.  The change is between accumulating *signed* area and accumulating *unsigned* area.

Comment: Awesome, thanks